# Which tyre will be abrased more during right hand drift with Audi rear sport differential?

Tags: lsd, quattro

Which tyre will be more abrased during right hand drift with Audi rear sport differential? My car is equipped with Torsen Quattro + rear electrohydraulic limited slip differential, it is an Audi S4 B8. I want to shave 0.5mm (1/32") of right rear tyre, which way I should drift? This is because I got damage to almost new tyres that have 7.5mm of tread while new have 8mm and they're expensive Pilot Super Sports.

Comment: On ice should be fine...

Comment: Hi Yoda. Your question is a little hard to follow. Are you trying to decide if you can drift your car as a way to deliberately wear down a specific tire by a specific amount?

Comment: If you are drifting your vehicle, tire damage is a given. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Shaving a tire takes tire off of your tires. My suggestion, either get scrub tires to put on while drifting, or ... don't drift.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 He has an AWD car that has slightly uneven tires. I think it would be very difficult to precisely wear down the new tire to be even with the other ones. You will most likely wear down both rear tires somewhat before they even out. I think some people have mentioned tire scrubbing services that specifically deal with this problem.

Comment: Drifting your car you should not be, “Once you start down the dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny, consume you it will.”

Comment: Additionally, unless you're doing this on snow (which won't wear your tires), I think it would be pretty hard to drift a Torsen AWD car with PSS's on tarmac. To my knowledge, most Audi's will tend to push rather than slide, although I'm not an expert so your experience may be different.